# Removing back to back dashes and asterisks in a string

Tags: java

I am having some trouble reading in a file and removing all of the punctuation from the file. 
Below is what I currently have and I can not figure out why "----" and "*****" would still occur.

Can anyone point me in a direction to figure out how I need to adjust my replaceAll() in order to make sure repeated occurrences of punctuation can be removed?

```
public void analyzeFile(File filepath) {
    try {
        FileInputStream fStream = new FileInputStream(filepath);
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fStream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        String textFile = "";
        String regex = "[a-zA-Z0-9\\s]";
        String putString = "";
        wordCount = 0;

        while ((textFile = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (!textFile.equals("") && textFile.length() > 0) {
                String[] words = textFile.split(" ");
                wordCount += words.length;
                for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                    putString = cleanString(regex, words[i]);
                    if(putString.length() > 0){
                        mapInterface.put(putString, 1);
                    }
                }
                putString = "";
            }
        }

        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error while attempting to read file: "
                + filepath + " " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

private String cleanString(String regex, String str){
    String newString = "";
    Pattern regexChecker = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher regexMatcher = regexChecker.matcher(str);
    while(regexMatcher.find()){
        if(regexMatcher.group().length() != 0){
            newString += regexMatcher.group().toString();
        }
    }
    return newString;
}
```

Comment: For completeness' sake, you should ask a question.

Comment: please add some more code to make this a minimal *working* example, with those vars declared, and an inspection of the result. Ideally a minimal `public class Test { public static void main(String[] args) { ... }}` that people can just run. If it goes wrong for "text file", it'll also go wrong for `String input = "hjuk** *++uihe hhued89 vwko****\nhus jgirw hifewq";` for instance.

Answer (score -1):

Surely you can use the `\w` escaped alphanumeric character? This will recognise all letters and numbers, but not punctuation.

```
putString = words[i].replaceAll("[^\w]+", "");
```

This replaces any non-word character with an empty string.

Comment: This seems as if it should be a comment. This code does not account for all punctuation, and is not scalable

Comment: why use `(..|..)` when we have grouping that lets us say `[*-]+`?